# How to merge two pandas dataframes on column of sets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have columns in two dataframes representing interacting partners in a biological system, so if gene_A interacts with gene_B, the entry in column 'gene_pair' would be {gene_A, gene_B}.  I want to do an inner join, but trying:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['gene_pair'])
```

throws the error

```
TypeError: type object argument after * must be a sequence, not itertools.imap
```

I need to merge on the unordered pair, so as far as I can tell I can't merge on a combination of two individual columns with gene names.  Is there another way to achieve this merge?

Some example dfs:

```
gene_pairs1 = [
    set(['gene_A','gene_B']),
    set(['gene_A','gene_C']),
    set(['gene_D','gene_A'])
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'r_name': ['r1','r2','r3'], 'gene_pair': gene_pairs1})

gene_pairs2 = [
    set(['gene_A','gene_B']),
    set(['gene_F','gene_A']),
    set(['gene_C','gene_A'])
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'function': ['f1','f2','f3'], 'gene_pair': gene_pairs2})

pd.merge(df1,df2,how='inner',on=['gene_pair'])
```

and I would like entry 'r1' line up with 'f1' and 'r2' to line up with 'f3'.

Comment: Can you provide a sample df1 and df2 that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple in the end: I used frozenset, rather than set.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u get an extra Id column for each pair and then join on that!
for eg.

```
df2['gp'] = df2.gene_pair.apply(lambda x: list(x)[0][-1]+list(x)[1][-1])
df1['gp'] = df1.gene_pair.apply(lambda x: list(x)[0][-1]+list(x)[1][-1])
pd.merge(df1, df2[['function','gp']],how='inner',on=['gp']).drop('gp', axis=1)
```

[image]